# Is submission to Corona Labs required or will the free version do?

Tags: coronasdk

Is it required to submit my code to corona labs for compilation for android game? Is free version enough for complete game development?

I am new to game developing and want to start with Corona SDK first for Android game. 
I read somewhere about it that you can not compile it on machine. You need to submit it online to Corona Labs and they give the final app. Is this correct?

If I use free version for 30 days and use the SDK then, does this make any difference or app compared to the full version? Or any issues I will face as I have used free version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit the compile button, it uses some stuff in Corona Labs servers, it looks like a normal local compilation, but it is not, mostly for anti-piracy I suspect.

Also the free version is purely for evaluation, to release anything you need to pay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see your point here. As I am learning game programming right now and don't want to pay, As well wish to add game on Google market, Do I have any other such good option? I was searching through internet and found about Cocos-2D but as I need to use C++, this will be my last choice. I like lua, do I have other option for it, like I can use lua and get free SDK for free in use for good game programming?..

Comment: Moai is open source, but annoyingly hard to setup (very hard...)
Gideros is free I think, but I never used it, so I cannot say what it does.
Other free SDKs for Android that I know are mostly C++

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Corona SDK converts your source to byte code locally and then it's validated against the servers and compiled in with the core libraries.  If you are not a paid subscriber, the resulting .apk (or App bundle for iOS) is altered so that when they are run on a device, you get a warning that you're using unlicensed evaluation software as well.

Corona is free to use to test and learn on, but when you are ready to release your app, then you have to buy a license.

Answer (score 0):

You might have noticed that CoronaLabs now offers a starter edition that is free-of-charge. This edition should be sufficient for indie game developers. It even comes with free cloud solutions for online multiplayer games and leaderboards.